# Faster way to Copy S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, boto

I am trying to copy around 50 million files and 15TB in total size from one s3 bucket to another bucket.
There are AWS CLI option to copy fast. But in my case, I want to put a filter and date range. So I thought to write code by using boto3.

The source bucket input structure:

> ```
> Folder1
>     File1 - Date1
>     File2 - Date1
> Folder2
>     File1 - Date2
>     File2 - Date2
> Folder3
>     File1_Number1 - Date3
>     File2_Number1 - Date3
> Folder4
>     File1_Number1 - Date2
>     File2_Number1 - Date2
> Folder5
>     File1_Number2 - Date4
>     File2_Number2 - Date4
> ```

So the purpose is to copy all files which start with 'File1' from each folder by using a date range(Date2 to Date4). date(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4) is file modified date.

The output would have date key partition and I am using UUID to keep every file name unique so it would never replace the existing file. So the files which have an identical date(modified date of the file) will be in the same folder.

Target Bucket would have output:

> ```
> Date2
>     File1_UUID1
>     File1_Number1_UUID2
> Date3
>     File1_Number1_UUID3
> Date4
>     File1_Number2_UUID4
> ```

I have written code by using boto3 API and AWS glue to run the code. But boto3 API copies 500 thousand files every day.

The code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2', config=boto_config)

# source and target bucket names
src_bucket_name = 'staging1'
trg_bucket_name = 'staging2'

# source and target bucket pointers
s3_src_bucket = s3.Bucket(src_bucket_name)
print('Source Bucket Name : {0}'.format(s3_src_bucket.name))
s3_trg_bucket = s3.Bucket(trg_bucket_name)
print('Target Bucket Name : {0}'.format(s3_trg_bucket.name))

# source and target directories
trg_dir = 'api/requests'

# source objects
s3_src_bucket_objs = s3_src_bucket.objects.all()

# Request file name prefix
file_prefix = 'File1'

# filter - start and end date
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=None)
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-06-15", "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=None)

# iterates each source directory
for iterator_obj in s3_src_bucket_objs:
    file_path_key = iterator_obj.key
    date_key = iterator_obj.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if start_date <= date_key <= end_date and file_prefix in file_path_key:
        # file name. It start with value of file_prefix.
        uni_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        src_file_name = '{}_{}'.format(file_path_key.split('/')[-1], uni_uuid)

        # construct target directory path
        trg_dir_path = '{0}/datekey={1}'.format(trg_dir, date_key.date())

        # source file
        src_file_ref = {
            'Bucket': src_bucket_name,
            'Key': file_path_key
        }

        # target file path
        trg_file_path = '{0}/{1}'.format(trg_dir_path, src_file_name)

        # copy source file to target
        trg_new_obj = s3_trg_bucket.Object(trg_file_path)

        trg_new_obj.copy(src_file_ref, ExtraArgs=extra_args, Config=transfer_config)

# happy ending
```

Do we have any other way to make it fast or any alternative way to copy files in such target structure? Do you have any suggestions to improve the code? I am looking for some faster way to copy files. Your input would be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Can you run `aws s3 sync` CLI as a command from your python script?

Comment: @Marcin The challenge with sync is to create a date key directory and exclude source directories(Folder1, Folder2, ..) in the target bucket 4. aws s3 sync s3://staging1 s3://staing2/api/requests --exclude "*" --include "*/File1*"

Comment: Check out the https://rclone.org/ tool

Comment: I've had success using S3 Batch Operations ... in short; your logic lives in a Lambda function, while S3 itself does the orchestration for you, invoking the lambda for each object ... it takes care of going through iterating through each object, invoking the lambda, collecting results, retrying, etc ... it's not fast but it is robust
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-basics.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely reason that you can only copy 500k objects per day (thus taking about 3-4 months to copy 50M objects, which is absolutely unreasonable) is because ***you're doing the operations sequentially.***

The vast majority of the time your code is running is spent waiting for the S3 Copy Object request to be sent to S3, processed by S3 (i.e., copying the object), and then sending the response back to you. On average, this is taking around 160ms per object (500k/day == approx. 1 per 160ms), which is reasonable.

To dramatically improve the performance of your copy operation, you should simply parallelize it: make many threads run the copies concurrently.

Once the Copy commands are not the bottleneck anymore (i.e., after you make them run concurrently), **you'll encounter another bottleneck: the List Objects requests**. This request runs sequentially, and returns only up to 1k keys per page, so you'll end up having to send around 50k List Object requests *sequentially* with the straightforward, naive code (here, "naive" == list without any prefix or delimiter, wait for the response, and list again with the provided next continuation token to get the next page).

Two possible solutions for the ListObjects bottleneck:

- If you know the structure of your bucket pretty well (i.e., the "names of the folders", statistics on the distribution of "files" within those "folders", etc), you could try to parallelize the ListObjects requests by making each thread list a given prefix. Note that this is not a general solution, and requires intimate knowledge of the structure of the bucket, and also usually only works well if the bucket's structure had been planned out originally to support this kind of operation.
- Alternatively, you can ask S3 to generate an inventory of your bucket. You'll have to wait at most 1 day, but you'll end up with CSV files (or ORC, or Parquet) containing information about all the objects in your bucket.

Either way, once you have the list of objects, you can have your code read the inventory (e.g., from local storage such as your local disk if you can download and store the files, or even by just sending a series of ListObjects and GetObject requests to S3 to retrieve the inventory), and then spin up a bunch of worker threads and run the S3 Copy Object operation on the objects, after deciding which ones to copy and the new object keys (i.e., your logic).

**In short:**

1. grab a list of all the objects first;
2. then launch many workers to run the copies.

One thing to watch out for here is if you launch an absurdly high number of workers and they all end up hitting the exact same partition of S3 for the copies. In such a scenario, you could end up getting some errors from S3. To reduce the likelihood of this happening, here are some things you can do:

- instead of going sequentially over your list of objects, you could randomize it. E.g., load the inventory, put the items into a queue in a random order, and then have your workers consume from that queue. This will decrease the likelihood of overheating a single S3 partition
- keep your workers to not more than a few hundred (a single S3 partition should be able to easily keep up with many hundreds of requests per second).

**Final note:** there's another thing to consider which is whether or not the bucket may be modified during your copy operation. If it could be modified, then you'll need a strategy to deal with objects that might not be copied because they weren't listed, or with objects that were copied by your code but got deleted from the source.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to complete it using [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops.html).

> You can use S3 Batch Operations to perform large-scale batch operations on Amazon S3 objects. S3 Batch Operations can execute a single operation on lists of Amazon S3 objects that you specify. A single job can perform the specified operation on billions of objects containing exabytes of data. Amazon S3 tracks progress, sends notifications, and stores a detailed completion report of all actions, providing a fully managed, auditable, serverless experience. You can use S3 Batch Operations through the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI, AWS SDKs, or REST API.
>
> Use S3 Batch Operations to copy objects and set object tags or access control lists (ACLs). You can also initiate object restores from Amazon S3 Glacier or invoke an AWS Lambda function to perform custom actions using your objects. You can perform these operations on a custom list of objects, or you can use an Amazon S3 inventory report to make generating even the largest lists of objects easy. Amazon S3 Batch Operations use the same Amazon S3 APIs that you already use with Amazon S3, so you'll find the interface familiar.

It would be interesting if you could report back whether this ends up working with the amount of data that you have, and any issues you may have encountered along the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) which is much faster and cheaper than `aws s3 cp` (up to 110x).

You can transfer data between buckets with the following command, after running `skyplane init`:

```
skyplane cp -r s3://<bucket-A>/ s3://<bucket-B>/
```

Comment: It really rocks - just transferred >300k files for just 16 minutes!